# Kubrick theme survival

Tags: css, wordpress

First, excuse me if I'm a noob. But my only way out of this condition is asking questions.

My blog (in swedish) at http://bluepen.se has suffered upgrade cancer. Somewhere around the switch from version 2 to 3 my theme went awful. I know, the Kubrick theme is outdated. But I would like to keep it, since I think modifying a new theme to my taste might be just as much work.

If I'm wrong in that assumption I will gladly switch to a supported theme.

However, take a look at it: The white #page background is cut off. And if you compare with -for example- the december 2013 archive view: It's not cut off.

The only place I find that manages this magic is style.css but I cannot find out what to do about it. I have looked at my blog with many different browser's DOM inspectors and I have tried a lot of different things but to no avail.

Is there anyone that can comment on this? Maybe some help, please?

Comment: There's a better way out: learn to read the [faq]'s & research (a lot) before asking ;)

Comment: It has to do, probably, with floatting elements. Try on #page to add: overflow:hidden; to make it wrap inside itself any floatting elements that it holds. border-radius and box-shadow is the easy CSS way to do this kind of layout, last time i set something this way was 6 years back :)

Comment: @GCyrillus is correct - I've just tried that myself in Chrome Devtools and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problems updating Kubrick if you want to change themes. I would suggest just trying a more recent default theme like twentythirteen. If it looks terrible you can always just change it back.

If you want to fix Kubrick @GCyrillis is correct but here is the step by step:

1. Go to style.css
2. Find the rule for #sidebar and remove `margin-left: 760px;` add `float: right;` You will now have no background for the main content.
3. Find the rule for #page and add `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Thank you so much mantis! That worked as a charm, a perfect christmas present for me :)

Comment: Great! Happy Christmas! Would you be so kind as to mark it as the correct answer then?